# Where does the stored procedure Searchinall come from?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

When I create a new database in SSMS either using the creation wizard or the `CREATE DATABASE` command the database will contain a stored procedure called *Searchinall*. This procedure has never been added to new databases previously, but since 2 days it will be created in every new database, no matter how I create it. I have tried creating a database from a different Computer on this server as well, but the stored procedure will still appear.

When I tried looking online for a procedure *Searchinall* I could not find any results, so I suspect it is not a new feature and nothing that should be created by default.

Could someone have maybe accidentally added it as a default stored procedure to be created in every new database on the server?
If so, how can I disable it?

Comment: Check the `model` database. All newly created Sql Server databases use the MODEL database as a template and any objects (tables, views, stored procedures, etc.) that exists in `model` be will a part of any new database created on that SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a new database in SQL Server the [Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-ver15) database is used as a template. Your new database will contain any stored procedurethat is in the model database.

From what you are describing it seems that the stored procedure, Searchinall is a custom procedure added to the model database by someone in your organization and then automatically included in any database that you created.

Comment: [TIL](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/today-i-learned-til) what the `model` system database was for! I've been using SQL Server for 17 years now and I never knew that!

Answer (score 4):

Usually, it is placed in the model database, that serves as default template when you create a new database. Try to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the model database. That is where new databases are copied from

Comment: ops, sorry, double answer